# getUser() always returns 0, even if I'm logged in

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm testing some code based on the example.php, and `getUser()` is returning 0, even though I'm currently logged in on FB.  Code on my index.php page as follows:

```
<?php

include 'fbLibrary/facebook.php';

$facebook=new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'myAppID',
        'secret' => 'mySecret',
        'cookie' => true
        ));


$user=$facebook->getUser();
echo "getUser() returned " . $user . "<p>";


if ($user)
{
    //fb query
    try
    {
        $me=$facebook->api('/me');
        print_r($me);

    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}


if ($me)
{
    $logoutUrl=$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>";
}

else
{
    $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'friends_status,publish_stream'
    ));
    echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
}

?>
```

When I go to the index.php page, the "getUser() returned" echo test returns 0.  And even though `$loginUrl` is set to a URL, when I click on it, it just takes me to the same index.php page.

If I log out of FB and reload the page, when I click "Login", I get taken to Facebook to login to my app.  Then when I've successfully logged in, I'm back at the index.php page with the non-functioning login URL, and getUser() continues to return 0.

I just downloaded the PHP SDK yesterday so I assume it's current.

Comment: Are you using the latest php sdk ? Have you set the site Url in app settings correctly ? Url in siteUrl and redirect url should be the same

Comment: @Jashwant, what do you mean by redirect URL?  I set this app up as a "Website with Facebook Login", there doesn't appear to be a field for redirect URL.  But the site URL is correct.

Comment: `https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk`

Comment: @Jashwant, yes, I got the SDK from this site.

Comment: This is very odd.  I just changed the AppId and Secret to the values for another app, and now `getUser()` returns my UserID.  I don't understand why; there is no difference between these two apps, other than their names.  And I've granted permissions to both apps.  But this works, for now.

Comment: And now it doesn't work again.  Very puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Then you could set the parameter domain of FB Class. Something like this:

```
<?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => APP_ID,//$app_id,
'secret' => APP_SECRET,//$app_secret,
'cookie' => true,
'domain'=>'xxxdomain.com',
));
$session = $facebook->getUser();
```